# Problem with recursive return type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a function:

```
let rec f1 x = f1 x;;
```

My question is - why OCaml gives me this:

```
a -> b ?
```

Why the returning type is different?

Comment: a is the type for x, b is the type for the returned value, which constraint do you see that should make them be equal?

Comment: Compare and contrast with ` let rec f1 x = if true then f1 x else x`

Answer (score 3):

Because this function never actually returns.

All `f1` does is call itself with the same argument, therefore creating an infinite loop.

Of course, the typing system cannot infer that your function is an infinite loop, but there is nothing in the code that lets it think that the return value is in any way linked to `x` and should have the same type.

The type `'a -> 'b` doesn't imply that `'a` and `'b` are different, just that they are not necessarily the same, and since the typing system found no information on the return type, it can only give it a fresh variable.

Let's see what the compiler will do when inferring your type.

```
let rec f1 x = (* f1 is a function, takes x as argument *)
         f1 x (* f1's return type is the same as that of (f1 x) *)
```

Given that, there is no indication that the function could return `x`, so no reason to believe that `f1` should be of type `'a -> 'a`. Hence the more general (and also compatible) `'a -> 'b`.

Comment: Actually is it certain that the types are different  (like ΔΔ).

Comment: Note that the type system does know that there is something fishy with functions that return any type. For instance, `let g () = f1 (); ()` will emit a warning about never-returning statement.

Comment: @octachron: I think that warning is for discarding a non-`unit` value on the left side of a `;`

Comment: Not in this case: the type of `f ()` can be unified with unit.  More precisely, the warning is `Warning 21: this statement never returns (or has an unsound type.)`